# Unable to update multiple records in Sybase database via jconn4.jar/Sybase driver version 7 & Mybatis framework

Tags: java, jboss7.x, sybase, mybatis, jconnect

I am using Mybatis framework for database persistence, connecting to Sybase database via Jconn4.jar and deploying my app on JBOSS 7 application server.

**1) Mybatis mapper - CustomerMapper.xml**

```
<update id="updateCustomerMapping" parameterType="java.util.Map" statementType="CALLABLE">
    {call sp_update_customer( #{account_customer,jdbcType=CHAR,mode=IN}, 
    #{customer_code,jdbcType=CHAR,mode=IN} )}
</update>
```

**2) Sybase Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_update_customer
(
    @account_customer varchar(10), 
    @customer_code varchar(12)=NULL 
)
```

**3) JBoss 7 standalone configuration**

```
  <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/SybaseDS" pool-name="SybaseDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:sybase:Tds:****:1000/****?chained=false</connection-url>
        <driver-class>com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver</driver-class>
        <driver>sybase</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>****</user-name>
            <password>****</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
           <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.sybase.SybaseValidConnectionChecker"/>
           <background-validation>true</background-validation>
           <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.sybase.SybaseExceptionSorter"/>
        </validation>
  </datasource>
```

Adding/Updating/Deleting single record works with Jconn4.jar but adding/updating/deleting multiple records does not work. 
I suspect the issue is with **jdbcType=CHAR** in mybatis mapper xml is not compatible with jconn4.jar.I also tried **jdbcType=VARCHAR** but still could not resolve this issue.

The same mapper configuration(jdbcType=CHAR) works with older version of Sybase driver - jconn3.jar.

Please help to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue using jconn4-7.jar. But if I use jconn4.jar it works.
So you can try to use this one.